# Convert an anonymous type list into binding list

Tags: c#, datagridview, anonymous-types, bindinglist

What happen is that after querying out a column from my table. I did a  .ToList() and use it as a dataSource for my datagridview. Now I have to get the function to remove the records from the datagridview working but the datasource have to be a binding list. But I have no idea how to convert an anonymous type list to a binding list. Can someone please shine upon me some light?

Answer (score 1):

I found a much better way to change it to a binding source. My goal was to remove rows... anyway here it is:

```
public partial class YourForm : Form {

 private BindingSource _source = new BindingSource();

 public YourForm() {
 List<Model> list = _service.GetList();
 _source.DataSource = list;
 _grid.DataSource = _source;
 }
}


Now you can play around with your datasource and the grid will behave itself. Don't forget to call _grid.Refresh() after each change.
```